# Print an image using a predefined image preset pragmatically

Tags: php, image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I simply need to print out an image via php in Drupal 7. I already have 3 presets, thumnail, medium and large. Does anyone know the exact code I need to print these out as I cannot seem to work it out?

As far as I know, in Drupal 6 it was something like this:

```
<img src="<?php print 'sites/default/files/imagecache/**thumbnail**/' . $node->field_image_cache['0']['filepath']; ?>" />
```

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [theme_image_formatter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7).

E.g.

```
print theme("image_formatter", array(
    'image_style' => 'thumbnail',
    'item' => array(
        'uri' => 'sites/default/files/image.jpg',
        'alt' => t(""),
        'title' => t(""),
        'attributes' => array(),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I cannot name the image (image.jpg), this needs to be a variable and take the image dependent on which node is being viewed?

Comment: Do you intend to print the image in the node page ?

Comment: Yes I do, what I am actually doing is using an image slideshow but taking a light coded one and dropping the variables into it. Then displaying it on nodes.

Comment: Then you should go to `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display` and click on the `gear icon` beside your image field, then choose the image preset you want to use.

Comment: This is not the problem, I just needed the php code to add into a view. I don't like the amount of code Drupal produces so I downloaded a lightweight jquery slideshow and now need to place the variables of my images into it, then drop it into a panel.

Comment: I am not understanding this still - how does the code know which node page is being viewed and what do I put in for the image variable. Where you wrote 'image.jpg' what goes in place of this? Truly grateful for any help. I need to use the code to serve the images that are associated with the node being viewed.